# How to trigger websocket frame fragmentation from the client?

Tags: websocket

I'm building a Web socket server, however, for testing purposes, I'd like Chrome or Firefox or any other browser to send the message fragmented so I can test my implementation.

I've tried even sending 100K text data and the FIN flag is always set to 1 and the opcode is TEXT.

Is there a way to manually trigger fragmented frames? Any client out there with more flexibility?

Comment: Have you tried some type of mocking framework to simulate fragmentation rather than try to trigger the behaviour from a browser?  (Also, I think packet fragmentation would be something that happens in various router/switch hardware that lives between your server and the client, not necessarily from the browser since it happens at a different layer in the TCP stack than the application layer ((http in your case)) )

Comment: Thanks. Currently I'm able to handle multiple recv() for the same message, so in that sense I think I'm covered.

Comment: @dev.glitch TCP or IP fragmentation does not result in WebSocket fragmentation. The former creates more IP packets and Ethernet frames, but does not alter the TCP sequence numbers. WebSocket fragmentation inserts extra WebSocket frame headers, which cause the TCP sequence numbers to shift. Therefore, a L2/L3 intermediary such as switch/router hardware (or even TSO in a NIC) will never cause WebSocket fragmentation. More substantial stream edits are required (especially if you want to test interleaved pings too) -- so you need something more like a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript WebSocket API does not expose this option. I recently ran into the same frustration when some more modern browsers (A Chromium derivative) was unpredictably sending fragmented WebSocket frames.

For testing I rolled my own TCP client sending pre-calculated fragmented WebSocket frames. Not ideal, but it got the job done, and AFAIK there's no alternative yet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into rolling my own client.

Comment: Ive had this same problem. on localhost no fragmentation, while on AWS sometimes it fragments. Maybe there's some kind of server environment araible or something that can define fragmentation, or an HTTP header?