# How to set the chunks size of WebSocket.send()?

Tags: javascript, websocket

**Context**

Hi, I have a LAMP server on which I am hosting a small interactive games website (to spend time during COVID). Recently I wanted to create real-time games so the approach PHP/MySQL is out the window. I started to develop a WebSocket server in C, with the intent that when "real-time" connection is required, clients can connect to it (using Javascript). For now everything works ok but I've only been sending/receiving small frames. I plan on sending larger frames eventually (>64kB), but because of my server architecture, I would prefer the frames not to exceed 32kB.

**Actual question**

Is there a way to control the chunking of `WebSocket.send()`?

I am looking at this website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket but I can't find anything refering to this. Even though in the tutorial they mention that messages can be sent in multiple frames of any size: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Message_Fragmentation.

If it's not possible is their a way to have better control on the WebSocket on the client side? (That would be universally supported ideally).

Comment: I just realized this question was already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387499/how-to-trigger-websocket-frame-fragmentation-from-the-client
But it's 4 years old! I can't believe the API hasn't been update since...